# Is there a way to do unit tests using private variables without increasing their visibility?

Tags: java

I have a MyClass I want to test.

I have a TestMyClass class I'm going to use for this.

In MyClass I have several private variables.

I want to run tests using these private variables in TestMyClass.

I can just go and change all these private variables to public and then use them as objects in TestMyClass, but is there a way to do the testing without increasing the visibility of these variables? That is without manually going in to TestMyClass, deleting the private visibility marker and entering a "public" visibility market.

Thanks!

Comment: aren't the private variables getting used in some public methods you want to test

Comment: Usually you do not want to test the internal state but what the class publicly exposes. Why would you care about the internal state if what is public is correct? The internal state is most probably correct too.

Comment: @DidierL It's my first time doing unit tests. Could you explain why we don't care about the internal state? Also, what exactly is the internalt state? Thanks!

Comment: Internal state is everything that is stored within your object and which is not publicly accessible. What you really want to test is the behavior of your class so that you are sure it works properly with other classes. As long as this is the case, you do not care about how it is implemented (internal state) and your tests should thus remain independent from the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with interacting with your private variables using getters/setters? You can use a `setUp()`/`@Before` method in your test class to set up the state you wish to test. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myInt;
    public void setMyInt( int i ) { this.myInt = i; }
    public int getMyInt() { return this.myInt; }

    public void addsTo( int add ) { return myInt + add; }
    ...
}


public class TestMyClass {
    MyClass my = new MyClass();
    @Before public void setup() { my.setMyInt( 42 ); }
    @Test public void testIs42() { assertEqual( "MyInt is 42" , my.getMyInt() , 42 ); }
    @Test public void testAddsTo() { assertEqual( "addsTo() works" , my.addsTo( 10 ) , 52 ); }
}
```

Makes sense? In this manner you only interact with the private variables through public methods. The `addsTo()` example is to illustrate that you would normally test the public methods the class exposes, not the getters/setters.

On a similar note, I often find myself changing method visibility from private to protected to allow testing class methods.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm quite newbish at Java, could you elaborate just a wee bit. Do I create the getters/setters in the test class?

Comment: @papercuts no, you generate them in the class you want to test. It's a common practice in Java to make variables private and control access to them via getXXX() and setXXX() method. Your IDE should be able to generate those for you, e.g. in Eclipse > right click > Source > generate Getters/Setter.

Answer (score 4):

its not adviced to test private memebers directly. The code should be designed in such a way that these private members will be indirectly called by public (interface) methods (example in your case: You can have setters and getters for member variables).

But you can use the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html) if you absolutely want to test private members.

Answer (score 2):

Why not provide setter / getter and use them instead of exposing variables?

Answer (score 2):

use public `setter and getters` for that private Properties in a class

Answer (score 2):

As explained in other answers, it is not necessary/advised to test private methods and/or access private fields. If you really want/have to do this, then [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) is the way to go.

If you have to access private attributes to set them, then [Spring's ReflectionUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html#setField%28java.lang.reflect.Field,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) can be very helpful. If you are using mockito, you can also use the [@InjectMocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation, which will inject any `@Mock`-annotated attribute in your test class in the tested object.

Otherwise, there is still the possibility to change a `public` access to a `protected` or `package private` access, which will be much more restrictive than `public`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to mark them as protected, then have a MyClassTestSupport that exposes them using getters/setters. However, this pattern doesn't work very well if your class is a base class for others...